# Is it possible to draw shapes within shapes using only for loops? If so,please point me in the right direction

Tags: c++, for-loop, drawing, shapes

I want to draw a simple square map, made out of a grid of asterisks and within the grid, I would like to draw other shapes.

example output:

```
xxxxxooxxxx
xxxxxooxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
ooxxxxxxxxx
ooxxxxxxxxx
```

I have tried simply putting the nested loops for the small shapes within the nested loops for the big shapes which resulted in some deformed infinite rectangle

and I have tried making the starting and ending conditions different for the smaller shapes (my thought process was that those were equivalent to coordinates but obviously thats wrong)

any help will be much appreciated, I hope to use loops to solve this but other methods are welcome too.

Here is my actual code
    {#include
    using namespace std;
    int main(){

```
    for(int row=0;row<26;row++)
    {
        for(int column=0;column<26;column++)
        {
            cout << "*";

        }
    cout<< endl;
    }

      for (int i=5;i<10;i++)
            {
                for (int j=5;j<10;j++)
                {
                    cout << "x";
                }
            cout << endl;
            }



}
```

The code currently draws 2 squares one 26x26 and one 5x5 right after that.
I'd like to know how to insert the 5x5 square into the 26x26square. I would also like to know how to control its position within the larger square

Comment: Show the code you're using if you want people to help you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: sorry but im not sure how to draw an example output on this forum since it keeps reading my enter keys as spaces.

but i meant to convey a rectangle made out of 'x' and 2 squares within it made of 'o'

Comment: Format the output as code (select it and click on the `{}` button). And also post your actual code, we can't help you without seeing your C++.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. Make sure you format it properly please.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to construct what you're trying to print first and then print it.  `cout` just prints to the console at the current position, and there's no simple way to reset that position inside the text that has already been output.  There are libraries that give you that functionality like `ncurses`, but that may be more than you're looking for.

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<char> GridRow;
typedef std::vector<GridRow> Grid;

void InitGrid(Grid& grid, int width, int height, char symbol = ' ')
{
    grid.clear();
    grid.resize(height);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); ++i)
    {
        grid[i].clear();
        grid[i].resize(width, symbol);
    }
}

void DrawRectangle(Grid& grid, char symbol, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    //Reject out of bounds rectangles.  An alternative would be to clip them.
    if(grid.empty() || grid.size() < static_cast<size_t>(y + height) || grid[0].size() < static_cast<size_t>(x + width))
    {
        return;
    }

    for(int h = y; h < (y + height); ++h)
    {
        GridRow& row(grid[h]);
        for(int w = x; w < (x + width); ++w)
        {
            row[w] = symbol;
        }
    }
}

void PrintGrid(const Grid& grid)
{
    std::string line;
    for(size_t h = 0; h < grid.size(); ++h)
    {
        const GridRow& row(grid[h]);
        for(size_t w = 0; w < row.size(); ++w)
        {
            std::cout << row[w];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Grid grid;
    InitGrid(grid, 11, 6, 'x');
    DrawRectangle(grid, 'o', 5, 0, 2, 2);
    DrawRectangle(grid, 'o', 0, 4, 2, 2);
    PrintGrid(grid);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    InitGrid(grid, 15, 15);
    DrawRectangle(grid, '*', 1, 1, 8, 8);
    DrawRectangle(grid, '*', 6, 6, 8, 8);
    PrintGrid(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

You might want to wrap the grid in a class to make things a bit cleaner, but I thought this might be easier to understand.